# How to remove header from zlib-compressed string?

Tags: python, zlib

I am compressing strings with `zlib` and a *dictionary* with power *9* and this is the script:

```
import zlib

__doc__ = """

rly this small py em ell thon... !? ha he hahaha hehehe h4ck3r wassup how ar u let's go lets go common c'mon...!!! ad

"""

class Compressor(object):
    def __init__(self, seed):
        c = zlib.compressobj(9)
        d_seed = c.compress(seed)
        d_seed += c.flush(zlib.Z_SYNC_FLUSH)
        self.c_context = c.copy()

        d = zlib.decompressobj()
        d.decompress(d_seed)
        while d.unconsumed_tail:
            d.decompress(d.unconsumed_tail)
        self.d_context = d.copy()

    def compress(self, text):
        c = self.c_context.copy()
        t = c.compress(text)
        t2 = c.flush(zlib.Z_FINISH)
        return t + t2

    def decompress(self, ctext):
        d = self.d_context.copy()
        t = d.decompress(ctext)
        while d.unconsumed_tail:
            t += d.decompress(d.unconsumed_tail)
        return t

c = Compressor(__doc__)

compressed_string = c.compress(string)

print compressed_string

string = "I installed python, and it's very nice and easy to use!"
compressed = c.compress(string)

print c.decompress(compressed)
```

My question is: From the resulting `compressed_string` how do you remove extra 'cuff' such as the header and last 4 ADLER bytes that is then appended later when decompressing? *Correct me if I'm wrong in some definitions.*

Like `12h3d78e23gdh278qs98qwjsj89qs1234` (where `12` is the theoretical 2 bytes header and `1234` the theoretical `ADLER` part at the end of the string) becomes `h3d78e23gdh278qs98qwjsj89qs` and is then rebuilt when zlib has to decompress with something like

```
to_decompress = '12',compressed,'1234' 
c.decompress(to_decompress)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already effectively stripped the header, since it resides in the first two bytes of `d_seed`.  You don't need to and should not strip the Adler-32 check, since if you reconstruct the compressed stream properly, the Adler-32 will provide an integrity check.

You just need to prepend `d_seed` to the transmitted data, and then decompress the result normally.

If you're using Python 3.3 or later, the better way to do this is to use zlib to do the dictionary thing for you.  The last argument of `zlib.compressobj()` and the last argument of`zlib.decompressobj()` can be the dictionary.  Then you also get an integrity check of the provided dictionary, to help verify that you're providing the same dictionary on the decompression end that was used on the compression end.  The stream is then a standard zlib stream for which a dictionary was used, and so is more portable and recognizable.

If you really want to squeeze out a measly six bytes (not recommended since you lose the integrity check), or really just four bytes since you already stripped the header, then use `-15` as the `wbits` argument to `zlib.*compressobj()`.  That will suppress the zlib header and trailer.  (Also requires 3.3.)

Comment: Background: I believe the OP wanted to forgo the checksum to try and produce as compact a compressed string as possible (chasing compression ratios for small strings). They were discussing their goals in the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: worth to mention that the zdict argument of compressobj & decompressobj are usable only on python 3.3 and above